# Is there any user-friendly nurbs modelling software

Tags: 3d, cad

I can`t find nurbs software like Rhino 3d (or Moment of Inspiration) with:
- ubuntu support
- user friendly interface
- iges, step, 3dm import-export

Comment: Blender is very good with nurbs. Its user-friendliness is somehow controversial, though (which is why I put my answer as a comment rather than a proper answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Sketch Up works pretty well with wine: http://wiki.winehq.org/GoogleSketchup

Comment: I know, but what about nurbs?